# Change ddsmoothmenu sub-menu side to the left

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

i want my site to display the sub-menu of the ddsmoothmenu menu to open to the left instead of the right.

how can i manage that?

check it on my site at the top: http://cor.co.il

(its in hebrew)

Comment: what is `ddsmoothmenu `?

Comment: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/ddsmoothmenu.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to edit the JS-file (Seems like you are using a plugin connected to Wordpress) you can add this to your css-file (layout.css line 111):

```
header #top-menu ul li ul {
     left: auto!important;
     right: 0;
}
```